# Including -std=c++11 compiler option correctly

Tags: c++11, makefile

I am looking to use C++ unordered_map data structure, but I think I am not passing the -std=c++11 option correctly.

1. main.cpp contains the main().
2. A.cpp needs to use the unorder_map DS.
3. A.cpp and B.cpp are accessed via main.cpp. There is a supporting header file main.h too.

The Makefile for the set of programs looks as follows:

```
CC  = g++
SRC = main.cpp B.cpp A.cpp
HDR = main.h
OBJ = main.o B.o A.o
FLAGS   = -std=c++11

all: main 
    $(CC) -o main $(OBJ) $(FLAGS)
```

I get an error telling me that A.cpp is not aware of the option -std=c++11. It would be great if you could let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: What compiler and version are you using? For gcc 4.3 to 4.6 the flag should be `-std=c++0x`.

Comment: It's g++ 4.7.1, but the problem with the Makefile has been addressed in the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that adding the following after "all: main", 'make' succeeds:

```
A.o: A.cpp
     g++ -c A.cpp $(FLAGS)
```

Comment: Compiler flags are for compilation, not linking, so you need to pass them to the compiler, not the linker (the compiler compiles source files to .obj files, the linker combines these .obj files to an executable). So yes this is the right place for the flags to be. Btw, you generally use CXX_FLAGS for C++ compiler flags.

Comment: Thanks for that piece of information. It seems I have been doing it incorrectly all this while.

Comment: The builtin macro for C++ compiler flags is actually `CXXFLAGS`

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks, yeah, that's right.. typo. Sigh, wish I could edit the comment :p